# Nodemailer send emails using original user account instead of alias

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-authentication, nodemailer

I have a problem with nodemailer where the user receive the email with sent from my google account which used to authenticate gmail instead of the alias used in mail options.

Below is my code:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: config.mailer.options.service,
    auth: {
        user: "xxxx@gmail.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});


var mailOptions = {
       to: user.email,
       from: 'Test Email <aaa@aaa.com>',
       subject: subject,
       html: emailHTML
};
```

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
Now when the user receive an email the email mentions that

> from: Test Email xxxx@gmail.com

Instead of showing

> from: Test Email aaa@aaa.com

Any help please

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348413/gmail-for-business-api-doesnt-allow-to-send-email-from-alias) might be related if you are using a business account.

Comment: @Tholle I got a response from nodemailer "Gmail always sends messages as the authenticated user. If you want to use custom address then use some other service", do you think that I can't solve this using both nodemailer and gmail API

Comment: Ah, I see :( I don't know if you can, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? (http://adilapapaya.com/docs/nodemailer/)

Comment: I'm looking for the solution yet - Any update

Comment: I think that you should use gmail api only https://mail.google.com, follow steps mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098461/nodemailer-gmail-what-exactly-is-a-refresh-token-and-how-do-i-get-one)

Comment: THIS SAME PROBLEM..
I ADDED SOLUTION..FIND MY ANSWER https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418737/send-email-via-nodemailer/49557206#49557206

Answer (score 3):

you also need to configure the alias in your gmail account. I faced the same issue but after configuring alias in gmail it worked. 
check this link to configure https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Now, with Gmail, you can use aliases as your main account. Just go into Gmail settings under account and select default.