# send email via nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I try to send email via nodemailer but getting error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined`. It looks like `sendMail` function is not defined. Any advise please?
P.S. This code for chatbot hosted on AWS

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

module.exports = function someName() {

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
      user: '7384093@gmail.com',
      pass: '*******'
  }
}))

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
  from: '"nerd studio" <7384093@gmail.com>', // sender address
  to: '7384093@gmail.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Подтверждение запроса \\ разработак чат-ботов \\ nerd       studio', // Subject line
  text: 'Добрый день! Вы оставили нашему Валере запрос и мы с радостью подтверждаем его получение. В ближайшее время с вами свяжется наш менелдер', // plaintext body
  html: '<b>Добрый день! Вы оставили нашему Валере запрос и мы с радостью подтверждаем его получение. В ближайшее время с вами свяжется наш менелдер</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  console.log(mailOptions);
  console.log(info);
   if(error){
       return console.log(error);
   }
   console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
 });
}
```

Comment: Where is the property `method` in the code provided?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to install npm nodemailer-smtp-transport, only nodemailer is enough to send email to gmail. But first, go to the https://myaccount.google.com/security google account and scroll down and check Allow less secure apps: ON and keep ON. you will send your gmail email. Here, is the full code -

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
app.post('/contactform', function (req, res) {


        var mailOpts, smtpTrans;

        //Setup Nodemailer transport, I chose gmail. Create an application-specific password to avoid problems.
        smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            //  host:'smtp.gmail.com',
            //  port:465,
            // secure:true,
            auth: {
                user: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
                pass: "xxxxxx"
            }
        }));
        var mailoutput = "<html>\n\
                        <body>\n\
                        <table>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>Name: </td>" + req.body.form_name + "<td></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>Email: </td><td>" + req.body.form_email + "</td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>MN: </td>" + req.body.form_phone + "<td></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>Messge: </td>" + req.body.form_message + "<td></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        </table></body></html>";
        //Mail options
        mailOpts = {
            to: "Your_App_Name <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
            subject: req.body.form_subject,
            html: mailoutput
        };

        smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, res) {
            if (error) {
                // res.send("Email could not send due to error" +error);
                return console.log(error);
            }
        });
        console.log('Message sent successfully!');
            res.render('contact.ejs');
    });
    //console.log(query.sql);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have nodemailer currently working this way: Create a file config/mail.js:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'yourHost',
    port: 2525, //example
    auth: {
        user: 'yourUser',
        pass: 'yourPass'
    }
});

module.exports = function(params) {
    this.from = 'yourEmail';

    this.send = function(){
        var options = {
            from : this.from,
            to : params.to,
            subject : params.subject,
            text : params.message
        };

        transporter.sendMail(options, function(err, suc){
            err ? params.errorCallback(err) : params.successCallback(suc);
        });
    }
}
```

And then, anytime I want to send an email:

```
var Mail = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config', 'mail.js'));

var options = {
    to: 'example@example.com',
    subject: 'subject',
    message: 'your message goes here'
}

var mail = new Mail({
    to: options.to,
    subject: options.subject,
    message: options.message,
    successCallback: function(suc) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    errorCallback: function(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
    }
});

mail.send();
```

Comment: How it could help me if the issue is with `sendMail` function?

Comment: Sure I did. I start thinking that this issue somehow related with AWS and serverless stuff. My chatbot hosted at AWS...

Comment: Using your solution I see that server tryes to get access to gmail which is my mail service but I do not receive emails.... I guess `sendMail` function should at least throw an error?! Or it's possibly gmail blocking my emails?

Comment: Is err undefined? I'm using smtp2go, maybe try that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.First you have to create an app in `Google Cloud Console` and `Enable Gmail API` from library.Get the credentials of your app.For that click on `Credentials` and in the place of `Authorized redirect URIs`keep this link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and save it.Next in another tab open this link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ click on  settings symbol on right side.And make a tick on check box(i.e,Use your own OAuth credentials) after this You have to give your clientId and clientSecret.And at the sametime on left side there is a text box with placeholder like `Input Your Own Scopes` there keep this link https://mail.google.com/
and click on Authorize APIs then click on `Exchange authorization code for tokens` then you will get your `refreshToken` and `accessToken` keep these two in your code.Hope this hepls for you.

```
    const nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
    const xoauth2=require('xoauth2');
    var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
    service:'gmail',
    auth:{
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user:'Your_Email',
    clientId:'Your_clientId',//get this from Google Cloud Console
    clientSecret:'Your_clientSecret',
    refreshToken:'Your_refreshToken',//get this from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
    accessToken:'Your_accessToken'
    },
    });
    var mailOptions={
    from:'<Your_email>',
    to:'Your firends mail',
    subject:'Sample mail',
    text:'Hello !!!!!!!!!!!!!'
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,res){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error');
    }
    else{
    console.log('Email Sent');
    }
    })
```

Comment: This sounds good but after I click "Authorize APIs" I get directed to a screen that says something like the app hasn't been verified and to go to safety. So I can't click on "Exchange authorization code for tokens"

Comment: Sorry for the late comment.Ofcourse you have to do..without clicking on Exchange authorization code for tokens button how can you get tokens....Don't affraid nothing happens...Just go on I completed my task....If you search for any other code you will notice that we have to give email password in code which is not secure.But with this code even you logged out from mail you can send mails using node....

Answer (score 0):

**I find solution for ,**
*How to send email from="userEmail" to="myEmail"?﻿*
**THIS IS TRICK**

```html
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer'); router.post('/contacts-variant-2', (req, res, next) => { var name=req.body.name; var email=req.body.email; var message=req.body.message; const output=`
<h3>Contact Details</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Name is : ${req.body.name}</li>
  <li>Email is : ${req.body.email}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<p>${req.body.message}</p>
`; var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ service: 'yahoo', auth: { user: 'create_new_email@yahoo.com', pass: 'password' } }); var mailOptions = { from:'create_new_email@yahoo.com', to:'myFriend@gmail.com', subject: name, text: 'Your have a new
contact request', html:output }; transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){ if (error) { console.log("errors is somthing "+error); res.send(404); } else { console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response); res.send(200); } }); });
```

Answer (score -2):

**Using Gmail**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Create the transporter with the required configuration for Gmail
// change the user and pass !
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

// setup e-mail data
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Our Code World " <myemail@gmail.com>', // sender address (who sends)
    to: 'mymail@mail.com, mymail2@mail.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }

    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

**Using Hotmail**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Create the transporter with the required configuration for Outlook
// change the user and pass !
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    tls: {
       ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@outlook.com',
        pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

// setup e-mail data, even with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Our Code World " <mymail@outlook.com>', // sender address (who sends)
    to: 'mymail@mail.com, mymail2@mail.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
    subject: 'Hello ', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }

    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

Alternatively, if your account is hotmail instead of outlook, you can use the buil-in hotmail service using the following transport:

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "hotmail",
    auth: {
        user: "user@hotmail.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});
```

**Using Zoho**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Create the transporter with the required configuration for Gmail
// change the user and pass !
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'myzoho@zoho.com',
        pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

// setup e-mail data, even with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Our Code World " <myzoho@zoho.com>', // sender address (who sends)
    to: 'mymail@mail.com, mymail2@mail.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
    subject: 'Hello ', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }

    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```